# Why is the access token that I pass to appEngine from iOS invalid?

Tags: ios, facebook, google-app-engine

I am working on an iPhone game that maintains a leaderboard and some social interaction through a backend that I built in Google App Engine.  The user can log in through facebook in the iPhone app.  The app sends some user details including the access token to my Google App Engine app through an HTTP post.

The handler that receives the request tries to use the access token to retrieve the users friends.  I am using the pythonforfacebook SDK (which I have had success with previously) which is on Github here:

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

The relevant python code in my GAE app is as follows:

```
def post(self):
    at = self.request.get('at')
    user = User.get_by_key_name(uid)
    if not user: #create previously unknown user
        logging.info('Entered unknown user code')
        logging.info(at)
        logging.info(type(at))
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(at) 
        facebook_user = graph.get_object("me")
        friends = graph.get_connections(facebook_user["id"], "friends")
```

The logging commands print what looks like a good access token and states that the type is 'Unicode'.  When I copy the access token that logging.info prints to the GAE logs and paste it into the facebook access token debugger, I get the following output:

App ID: **deleted for privacy but looks right**

Metadata:   {"sso":"iphone-safari"}

User ID: **deleted for privacy but looks right**

Issued: 1345405177 (10 minutes ago)

Expires: Never

Valid:  True

Origin: Mobile Web Faceweb

Scopes: offline_access read_stream

I just updated my code to use the most recent posted version of pythonforfacebook but that didn't make any difference.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dessie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get friends of the user you can do it pretty easily without the pythonforfacebook SDK.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<username or ID>/friends?access_token=<your token>
```

That link will give you the friends of the user in JSON format. So if you import `urllib2` and `json` you could do:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(<url above>)
friendsString = response.read()
friends = json.loads(friendsString )
```

Then `friends` will be a [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) containing of all the friends.

Comment: So that was what I did originally but it wasn't working.  That's why I turned to pythonforfacebook.  I tried what you suggested again and I think I found the problem.  When I run the following command: url = "http s://graph.facebook.com/"+user.id+"/friends?access_token="+user.access_token.  The resulting string has inverted commas around the access token.  I tried cutting and pasting into the browser address bar and it failed but it worked when I deleted the inverted commas.  I don't know why they are there and I'm not sure how to get rid of them.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure on your setup but could you use string.replace to get rid of the inverted commas? `user.access_token = user.access_token.replace("'","")`

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks for your help.  I suppose I should have thought of that, I'm still not that fluent in Python.